# Docker-compose python manage.py no such file or directory

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose to run three containers. Two of them depends on database so I'm using `wait-for-it.sh` to make sure they are not run until database is listening.

This is `my docker-compose.yml` file:

```
  web:
    build: ./docker/web
    command: ["./wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--", "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8080"]
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
      - spider
    links:
      - db
```

When I run `docker-compose up` command I get the error:

```
web_1     | wait-for-it.sh: waiting 15 seconds for db:5432
web_1     | wait-for-it.sh: db:5432 is available after 0 seconds
web_1     | python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

When I add volume `.:/src` the `manage.py` is found but `wait-for-it.sh` isn't:

```
ERROR: for web  Cannot start service web: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"./wait-for-it.sh\": stat ./wait-for-it.sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

I added `wait-for-it.sh` file to the directory where Dockerfile for `web` service is.

Any idea how can I make this work?

**EDIT**
Here's the Dockerfile used in docker-compose:

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /src
COPY . /src
WORKDIR /src
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Can you include your `Dockerfile` in the question?  Are correctly `COPY`ing your application code in?

Comment: @DavidMaze I included the Dockerfile. Sorry for not doing it ealier.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing approach. Added healthcheck to db service:

```
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:5432"]
  interval: 5s
  timeout: 30s
  retries: 5
```

And restart policies to other services:

```
restart: on-failure
```